# What is the difference between bash arrays with the notation ${array[*]} and ${array[@]}

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm curious if these are just synonyms or if there is any difference among these two notations used to iterate through an array in bash:

```
${array[@]}

${array[*]}
```

I use both in the same way and they don't seem to yield different results:

```
array=(one two three four)
for stuff in ${array[@]} ; do echo $stuff ; done
one 
two
three
four
```

returns the same as:

```
array=(one two three four)
for stuff in ${array[*]} ; do echo $stuff ; done
one 
two
three
four
```

Is there any difference or should I consider both identical?

Comment: Compare `printf "%s\n" "${array[*]}"` and `printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"`.